# svn ignore files is not working for svn add

Tags: svn

I have a folder of files generated but certain files i want to ignore when i add them.

I firstly did a

```
svn add -N FolderName
svn propset svn:ignore '*.dump' .
```

then when I do

```
svn status
```

I see that everything except the ignored files with a question mark in front.

then when i do

```
svn add *
svn status
```

everything includes the files i ignored are added.

I don't want to upload these dump files but ignore does not help me with this.

Could someone provide some idea on how to do this as all the answers I see online basically is just what i described above.

Comment: Did you commit these changes?

Comment: when i commit they get committed.